# Are there technology tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

To be more specific are there tags for:

- medieval technology
- magic-enhanced medieval technology
- modern technology
- magic-enhanced modern technology
- futuristic technology
- magic-enhanced futuristic technology

If there are tags which are similar then what are they? If not then is there a way to make them?

Comment: I can get behind "magitek" to specifically mean "technology infused with magic" instead of both tags which could also mean "technology working together with distinct magic", but I don't think "future-tech" is useful. Using "far-future" to show the time and "technology" to show the topic should be enough and I don't think the demand to add exactly four other tags to a new question is that great that the site would benefit from these combinations. Therefore I downvote this proposal.

Comment: Remember that voting is different in meta. It does not necessarily mean "this question is poorly written". It may also mean "I don't agree with what you are proposing" - here, downvote may well mean that downvoter don't want you to go and create that tag.

Comment: @Secespitus "magitek" is what i am looking for. is there anything i need to do?

Comment: @ajnatorixzersolar As you currently don't have the reputation you need someone with at least 300 reputation to do that. F1Krazy made the suggestion so we are already two users who have the reputation and you who think this tag would be good. If other members of the community think it would be a good tag, too, I will happily create it for you. Let's wait 24 hours for other members to voice their opinion and if the consensus is that "magitek" is probably okay you can ping me and I'll add it to a question of yours.

Comment: It might help if you could explain what those tags mean. I personally can only guess

Comment: @Raditz_35 medieval, modern and futuristic seem self explanatory, magic -enhanced is for where the setting also has magic (used for resources, power, energy source etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a quick look through the tags, and those specific tags don't exist. There is a single tag for [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology), a single tag for [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), and individual tags for [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval), [modern-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-age), [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future), and [far-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-future). If you wanted to ask about "magic-enhanced modern technology", you would have to use [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic), [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology), and [modern-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-age) all together.

> If not then is there a way to make them?

Creating tags is a privilege, for which you need [300 reputation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Once you have that privilege, creating a tag is as simple as typing the tag name into the "tags" box when asking a new question.

The real question, however, is whether it's worth *having* such specific tags.

My understanding is that if a tag doesn't get used often enough, and/or tends to get used in low-quality questions, it gets removed. [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) have been used together 68 times, but at a glance, not many of those questions are specifically about magic-enhanced technology, and about half of them have been closed.

As for specific time periods, [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) has been paired with:

- [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future) - 35 questions
- [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) - 32 questions
- [far-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-future) - 12 questions
- [modern-age](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-age) - 12 questions

There are exactly 5 occasions on which [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) *and* [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) have been paired with *any* of those four time-period tags.

In conclusion:

- I would support the creation of a "magitek" tag, for questions about magic-enhanced technology
- I would *possibly* support the creation of "future-tech" and "medieval-tech" tags, for questions about technology from specific eras, but will defer to community consensus on whether those tags are needed.
- I do not believe that the other tags you requested are necessary, as there does not appear to be enough demand for them.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer to include a link to the specific privilege. It's at 300 rep. I can get behind "magitek" to specifically mean "technology infused with magic" instead of both tags which could also mean "technology working together with distinct magic", but I don't think "future-tech" is useful. Using "far-future" to show the time and "technology" to show the topic should be enough and I don't think the demand to add exactly *four* other tags to a new question is that great that the site would benefit from these combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the creation of all those tags.  The purpose of tagging is not to rewrite your question using the fewest number of tags but to identify the major topics your question depends on.  The value of tags is to help people find your question.  As tag specificity increases, the number of people subscribing to the tag decreases.

*Which means you'll have far more people subscribing in total to [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) than you ever would a single "medieval technology" tag.  The single tag doesn't help you.  It hurts you.*

**Which is a long way of saying, you actually want all those individual tags.**

New tags should only be created when a specific context or issue cannot be constructed using the existing tags AND that context or issue would be of importance to many other people.  You'd be surprised how many tags have been created that have been attached to only one question: the question asked by the OP who created the tag.  Those new tags did ***absolutely nothing*** for the OPs that created them.

*Another way of looking at the purpose of tags is this: they're advertising.  In advertising you want as many people as possible to notice your product.  Seeing the tag only after you arrive at the question means the tag was useless.*

Therefore, (and ruthlessly using Secespitus' example), It is a legitimate question to ask, "is there enough confusion between 'tech infused with magic' and 'tech and magic working together' to justify a new tag?  Sucespitus believes there is.  To determine the veracity of his belief we would need to look at all the questions using both the [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) and [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) tags and discover how many (as a percentage of the whole) were about tech infused with magic.  If the answer is less than 5%, you might not be helping anyone by creating the tag as the statistic suggests few people are interested in the topic.