# Is there a tag where a user can specify the technological level range his answer applies to?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I have a question in sandbox where the technological level will determine the viability of the answer. My idea was to make an intergalatic call for bids. So any entities could apply.

Answers would represent such entities specifying their technological level and the time to apply their solution.

But I still want answers and the question to not be a mess, so it will be science-based.

Is there a tag that will allow that?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Are there technology tags?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5848/are-there-technology-tags) the answer is that there aren't any technology tags. Tags should be used as a means of categorizing questions, not to define what the question is about. You could use tags for some time frames such as [far-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/far-future). The implicit assumption is that questions should be based in present day science, but as you are introducing a seemingly all-mighty Entity it's important to define what your entity is capable of.

My intention with my comments in the Sandbox was that you should edit your draft to explain the abilities of your entity, possibly thinking about in terms of a technological level as it basically said "I have a super powerful entity that wants to move the Earth - how?" to which the answer would be "Use the super powers of your entity", which is not a useful answer. Thinking in terms of "My entity can do things humans could do now" or "My entity can do things a Kardashev Type 2 civilization could do" would discourage answers that amount to "Use magic".

My request for what tags you should use and which technological level you want were two separate things.

Comment: Sorry if you had to post you usefull comment out side of the sandbox. Power will be simply a gravitational force. it's a planet, the first one. How can it be on the path of earth twice, the answer is Chaos. From my reading it must be around Type 3. But a Type 4 can apply. Even a Type 2 if it as the creativity to brings a genius solution. This in only an canvas to brings the best solution out of Kardashev Type. This was what was in my mind when I add this question.

Comment: Thats also why "love" is in the question because it can be a exact copy of Hadean Earth. It has to be our Earth.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying. Are you sure that "Entity" is the correct word? It seems to me like "civilization" would be more appropriate. I thought you were talking about some unknown godlike entity the whole time and not about a civilization on a different technological level. And you say that "it can be an exact copy of Hadean Earth. It has to be our Earth" - so, is a copy okay, or does it have to be the original?

Comment: @Secespitus Entity can cover a lot of different things. Individuals, groups, it could possibly include systems but not processes. A godlike entity could be an alien godlike super-being or an alien super-civilization. In other words, precision & clarity helps in knowing what the entity is. Put me down as agreeing with your point.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are for classifying questions so that it's easier to find relevant questions when searching. They should be supplemental to the question, and not required to interpret the question correctly. There are no tags for answers.

If you have a question which is applicable for a range of tech levels then tagging it with a tech level tag is probably not the best use of tags.